# iPhoto library was deleted, had me create a new library. Went into Finder & don't have the "Masters" folder. Where are my original photos?

Tags: macos, finder, photos.app

I did a little research, & I found numerous websites directing me to go to iPhoto on Finder, right click, & click on "Show Package Contents". When I click on it, I am directed to a folder that says "Contents".

However, when I open that folder, I was promised there would be a folder called "Masters", but I found 8 folders and 4 other items- none with the name "Masters" & none of the folders had my original pictures.

To be more specific, the names of the folders I have are: _CodeSignature, _MASReceipt, Frameworks, MacOS, Library, PlugIns, Resources, and XCPServices.

Are my photos gone forever?

Comment: maybe if you explain how the Delete happened. And do you use iCloud for photo back up?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not use iCloud for back up.

A messaged popped up while I was on iPhoto saying "iPhoto needs a photo library to continue. You may choose an existing iPhoto library or create a new one."

There were 3 buttons to choose from "Quit"   "Create Library..."  &  "Choose Library..." I was so confused, I think I hit create library, and all my photos were deleted and I was redirected to iPhoto's introduction page

Comment: It sound like you just set up a new Lib rather than finding your existing one. Launch iPhoto & immediately hold the Alt [Option] key. Wait until you see that same message again. Select "Choose Library" & then find it in Mac HD/Users/[yourname]/Pictures. There may be 2 in there [due to your last attempt], you want the biggest one.

Answer (score 1):

> I think ...

That's a bad beginning. You need to know what you did.

> I hit create library, and all my photos were deleted and I was redirected to iPhoto's introduction page

When you entered a name, did it ask "___ exists. Replace?"

> ...go to iPhoto on Finder...  the names of the folders I have are: _CodeSignature, _MASReceipt, Frameworks, MacOS, Library, PlugIns, Resources, and XCPServices.

That's the iPhoto application. Not the iPhoto Library. Look in Home -> Pictures for something like "Theresa's iPhoto Library" and double-click on it.